# How can we check if a website is actually running or not?

Tags: http, scrapy, urllib2

I'm using python urllib2 module.
code snippet

```
try:
      code =urllib2.urlopen(req).getcode()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
      code = e.getcode()
      print e.getcode()
except urllib2.URLError,e:
      f = open('report.txt','a')
      f.write("%d     %s      %s\n"%(startup['id'],startup['name'],startup['website']))
      f.close()

except:
     #f.write("%d     %s      %s"%(startup['id'],startup['name'],startup['website']))
     pass
```

But there is a problem in  sites like "http://www.raddiwale.in/" getting response code =200  but still site is not alive.

Comment: So how to list such websites too ?

Comment: easyanalytics.in  this is another example of same site.